# watir method conflicts with my ruby class

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, nomethoderror

Hi guys i'm doing some automations scripts with Watir and trying to create a ruby class to make it better but i'm having this error:

> examen.rb:6:in 'enterEmail': undefined method 'text_field' for # (NoMethodError)

This is part of my conflictive code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
class LoginPage 
  def enterEmail (email)
    text_field(:user, :id => 'user_email').set email
  end
end
```

The problem that i see is: i did not define the 'text_field()' method in my class just because is a Watir method... Anyone knows how can i use the watir method in the classes that i create?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `text_field(:user, :id => 'user_email')`? That would not be a valid call for a Watir::Browser. Are you perhaps confusing usage with the page-object gem?

Comment: I just tried to complete the 'user_email' text field, but the problem was bigger than that. The way to solve this was creating an instance of a browser and apply the text_field method to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text_field` is an instance method of The `Watir::Browser` class. If you want to use it, you have to call it on an instance of that class.

```
class LoginPage
  def initialize()
    @b = Watir::Browser.new
  end 

  def enterEmail (email)
    @b.text_field(:user, :id => 'user_email').set email
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, your class does not have any `text_field` method. This method is a defined on `Watir::Browser` instance. In your example, haven't created one.

```
class LoginPage 
  def initialize
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
    @browser.goto "http://example.com"
  end

  def enterEmail (email)
    @browser.text_field(:user, :id => 'user_email').set email
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Both Yossi and Martin have correct answers. But because you're defining a `LoginPage` class, you should probably look into the [page-object](http://github.com/cheezy/page-object) gem. This lets you define a `text_field` almost identical to the code you already have. Your class would look like:

```
class LoginPage
  include PageObject

  text_field(:user, :id => 'user_email')      

  def enter_email(email)
    self.user = email
  end
end
```

And you'd execute it like:

```
login = LoginPage.new(browser)
login.enter_email("my_email@example.com")
```